# How to increase volatile int in java using multiple thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

I have a volatile int variable with value `0` that I want to increase up to `100` using 5 thread. I am trying to generate result from `0` to `100` with no duplicate. Can anyone please help me to resolve this.

I try this approach. Is it proper?

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {
    VolatileIncrement vo = null;
    String str = null;
    Producer(VolatileIncrement vo, String str){
        this.vo = vo;
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(vo.i < 100){
            System.out.println(str+vo.increaseI());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
}

public class VolatileIncrement {    
    volatile Integer i = 0;
    public synchronized int increaseI() {
            i++;
            return i;
        }
    }
}

public class ProducerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VolatileIncrement vo = new VolatileIncrement();
        Producer p1 = new Producer(vo,"I am thread 1 - ");
        new Thread(p1).start();
        Producer p2 = new Producer(vo,"I am thread 2 - ");
        new Thread(p2).start();
        Producer p3 = new Producer(vo,"I am thread 3 - ");
        new Thread(p3).start();
        Producer p4 = new Producer(vo,"I am thread 4 - ");
        new Thread(p4).start();
        Producer p5 = new Producer(vo,"I am thread 5 - ");
        new Thread(p5).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Comment: I try the below approach.

Comment: `volatile` is preferred to be used in the cases of require assignment and auto cache flush. in your case, since addition and assignment both together can be operated atomically. you will either need to use synchronized, or as the others say, use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: is there any reason that you can't use the `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`???

Comment: Yes. AtomicInteger is also resolved the issue. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use atomic[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) classes for the update an integer by multi-threads

```
AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);
counter.getAndIncrement();
```

It is lock-free and thread-safe on single variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter=0;
public static synchronized void increase()
{
     counter++;
}
```

Call this method.. Since its declared synchronized only one thread will act at a time (i.e. increment at a time).

Answer (score 0):

a) there is no reason to use volatile if all accesses to that variable is within a synchronized block. Synchronized has a larger scope than volatile for syncing memory between threads.

b) you cannot make a simple i++ atomic; you need synchronization, or reentrant locks, or the said AtomicInteger.